# Better way of multiplayer IFs with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Im wondering if I am tackling this in the best way or if there is a better way of achieving my task.

I've written a function in PowerShell which takes different parameters, but some of the parameters won't work together.

So for example if I'm running the function and specifying a computerName parameter then I can't also pass list of multiple computer names.

I know I can write multiple If statements as along the lines if If(($computerName) - and ($computerList)){Then write and error}

but there are several parameters not just two, so do I need to do an if for each set of parameters someone could type in, or is there a better way of me tackling this?

currently I have multiple Ifs like If $computerName -and !(log file) and $computerlist) then write an error etc.

Comment: Use [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets) to declare mutually exclusive parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell-idiomatic solution here is to declare a parameter that accepts *either*:

```
function Get-Stuff
{
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName
  )

  process {
    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
      # do stuff with each individual -ComputerName argument
    }
  }
}
```

Now the user can do both

```
Get-Stuff -ComputerName oneComputerName
```

... and

```
"many","computer","names" |Get-Stuff
```

or for that matter

```
$computers = Get-Content .\Computers.txt
Get-Stuff -ComputerName $computers
# or
$computers |Get-Stuff
```

---

> I know I can write multiple `If` statements as along the lines of `If(($computerName) -and ($computerList)){Then write and error}`

You can, but this is generally a bad idea - to test whether an argument value was passed to a parameter is better done through the automatic variable `$PSBoundParameters`:

```
function Get-Stuff
{
  param(
    [string]$AParameter,
    [string]$ADifferentOne
  )

  if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('AParameter')){
    # an argument was definitely provided to $AParameter
  }

  if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ADifferentOne')){
    # an argument was definitely provided to $ADifferentOne
  }
}
```

---

The answer to the implied question of "how do I declare and work with mutually exclusive parameters" is [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets):

```
function Verb-Noun
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'SingleComputer')]
    [string]$ComputerName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'MultipleComputers')]
    [string[]]$ComputerList

  )

  if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'SingleComputer'){
    # just one, we can deal with $ComputerName
  }
  else {
    # we got multiple names via $ComputerList
  }

}
```

PowerShell now recognizes two distinct parameter sets, each of which only accepts one of our parameters:

```
PS ~> Get-Command Verb-Noun -Syntax

Verb-Noun -ComputerName <string> [<CommonParameters>]

Verb-Noun -ComputerList <string[]> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: yes I had thought about doing it like that, but the way id written the function was so if a computerist is provided (ie from a text file) then they have to specify a log file path and optional an output file path, whereas with a single computer then the log file isn't needed and nor would an output file be needed as it just displays the output on the screen.....but then realised doing it that way I would need lots of if statements to check what parameters they have entered at the command line

Comment: @deniscooper I updated the answer with an example of how to check `$PSBoundParameters` instead of the variables themselves, might also be useful

Comment: that looks good, I haven't seen this before so will take a look and see if I can get this to work. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: just wanted to say the parameter set did exactly what I wanted it to do so thank you